# Avoid same Lat Lng on Google Map Animation in android

Tags: android, json, google-maps, animation, google-maps-api-3

I am implementing animation in google map using [this](http://ddewaele.github.io/GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock/part3) example. I am getting LatLng data from a server. But the problem arises when I get too many data for a single point on map. The animated marker wait on a single point so long as there are data for that point. Please see the following sample code

```
for (i = 0; i < jsonAssets.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject nlmJsonObject = jsonAssets.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONObject lastData_JsonObject = nlmJsonObject.getJSONObject("last_data");
                        JSONObject nlm_locJsonObject = lastData_JsonObject.getJSONObject("loc");
                        JSONArray coordinated = nlm_locJsonObject.getJSONArray("coordinates");

                        Log.d("LASTLATLONG_ANIMATION", coordinated.toString());

                        latt = (double) coordinated.get(0);
                        lng = (double) coordinated.get(1);
                        addMarkerToMap(new LatLng(lng, latt));

                    }    
                    animator.startAnimation(true);
```

How can I check and omit similar points to make my map animation smoother?

Thanks

Comment: Make 'latt' and 'lng' paremeters global, then compare new and previously set values at each jsonAssets object. If current and previous are same, skip to other jsonAssets object.

Comment: Can you please give me a sample to compare the current and previous latlng because I already tried it but could not implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just edited your code, to give the idea

```
private double latt;
private double lng;

private void showMarkers(){

    // Your other codes

    for (i = 0; i < jsonAssets.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject nlmJsonObject = jsonAssets.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONObject lastData_JsonObject = nlmJsonObject.getJSONObject("last_data");
        JSONObject nlm_locJsonObject = lastData_JsonObject.getJSONObject("loc");
        JSONArray coordinated = nlm_locJsonObject.getJSONArray("coordinates");

        Log.d("LASTLATLONG_ANIMATION", coordinated.toString());

        // Current values
        double currentLat = (double) coordinated.get(0);
        double currentLng = (double) coordinated.get(1);

        // Compare. If not same add the marker
        if(currentLat != latt && currentLng != lng){
            latt = (double) coordinated.get(0);
            lng = (double) coordinated.get(1);

            addMarkerToMap(new LatLng(lng, latt));
        }

    }
    animator.startAnimation(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to add a new marker only when it's location is farther than a given distance to the last marker added.

My example uses the `SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween` from the [Google Maps API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/) to compute the distance betwen two LatLng objects:

```
final float MIN_DISTANCE = 10; // Minimum distance in meters to consider that two locations are the same
LatLng lastLatLng = null;

// ...

for (i = 0; i < jsonAssets.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject nlmJsonObject = jsonAssets.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject lastData_JsonObject = nlmJsonObject.getJSONObject("last_data");
    JSONObject nlm_locJsonObject = lastData_JsonObject.getJSONObject("loc");
    JSONArray coordinated = nlm_locJsonObject.getJSONArray("coordinates");

    Log.d("LASTLATLONG_ANIMATION", coordinated.toString());

    latt = (double) coordinated.get(0);
    lng = (double) coordinated.get(1);

    LatLng currentLatLng = new LatLng(latt, lng);

    if (lastLatLng == null || SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(lastLatLng, currentLatLng) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
        addMarkerToMap(new LatLng(lng, latt));
        lastLatLng = currentLatLng;
    }
}
animator.startAnimation(true);
```

Comment: This is right too, but '10 meter' a bit dangerous. Suppose that each sequential marker has distance lower than 10 meters. In this case only first marker could be added.

Comment: You are right, thats the idea. When working with locations, depending on where the data come from you can receive several very close locations that are virtually the same. As @codehub wants to animate the map traversing several markers and doesn't want the map to stop too much time on the same point, comparing coordinates may not be enough in certain situations (too close locations that should be cosidered the same). Of course you can change the value 10 to be whatever you need (maybe you need to set it to 1 meter in one scenerio and 100 meters in other)

Comment: Can you tell me the idea to draw lines on the streets that are available on Google maps? Right now we are connecting only points but it does not go through the street lines. While we search for any location or distance of two locations the Google Map shows the route. How can we implement the same idea while  drawing animation on Google Map?

Comment: You can use the Google Directions API to implement that functionality, but you should ask another question so other people can help you (the new question with it's answers can help others as well)

Comment: Ok I will ask another question.